# Расположить view по центру между двумя элементами в RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-relativelayout

В RelativeLayout сверху расположен LinearLayout, а снизу - RecyclerView. В данный момент ImageView расположен по центру экрана. Каким образом его можно расположить по центру между LinearLayout и RecyclerView? Пока напрашивается способ с программным заданием отступа в соответствии с высотой верхнего и нижнего элементов. Есть ли какое-то более рациональное решение?

Comment: Два варианта: обернуть в контейнер, умеющий центровать (ака `RelativeLayout`) ; или заполнить им весь промежуток, но саму картинку расположить по центру (атрибут `android:scaleType="center"` , если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @woesss так вот как можно заполнить им весь промежуток, если верхний и нижний элементы имеют высоту wrap_content?

Comment: Замените корневой контейнер на вертикальный `LinearLayout`, а `ImageView` задайте вес: `android:layout_weight="1"` и высоту в `0dp`